# Open an application and then click a button in that application programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button

I would like to open an application and then click a button in that application, for example I'm opening Microsoft Paint and I'm trying to click the "Fill with color" button that has a bucket image.

[image]

I have only put the process starting code and don't know where to begin

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Process P;
    public IntPtr WindowHandle;
    public Image TargetButton;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        TargetButton = Bitmap.FromFile("Bucket.JPG");

        P = Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\mspaint.exe");
        WindowHandle = P.MainWindowHandle;

        // now to find that button and click it, I have the button stored as image in TargetButton variable above
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684021.aspx) APIs.

In the following example I supposed there is an open instance of `mspaint` and then I found `Fill with color` button and clicked on it. As a result, you will see the toolbar button will be selected.

To do so add a reference to `UIAutomationClient` and `UIAutomationTypes` assemblies and add `using System.Windows.Automation;` Then use the following code:

```
var paint = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("mspaint")
                    .FirstOrDefault();
if (paint != null)
{
    var paintMainWindow = paint.MainWindowHandle;
    var root = AutomationElement.FromHandle(paintMainWindow);
    var fillButton = root.FindAll(TreeScope.Subtree, Condition.TrueCondition)
        .Cast<AutomationElement>()
        .Where(x => x.Current.Name == "Fill with color").FirstOrDefault();
    if (fillButton != null)
    {
        var invokePattern = fillButton.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern);
        if (invokePattern != null)
            ((InvokePattern)invokePattern).Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Paint was just an example. OP was looking for a general solution.

Comment: @PepitoSh When OP accepts the answer it means the answer is quite satisfying.

Comment: It is satisfying, alright. I'd suggest though an edit to the OP to reflect how a particular solution would solve a general problem.

Comment: @PepitoSh If you are familiar with UI Automation you can the answer is showing how to find an element and how to click on it. I can say, it's a good answer and while It's not going to be a general answer, it's general enough.

Comment: @PepitoSh I noticed that you have deleted your answer after getting downvoted. Downvoting the question which you also have tried to answer, is not a good idea. JFYI I'm not the downvoter to your answer, I just got downvote from the same person who downvoted your answer.

Comment: Downvotes should not be used because of personal hostility or biased. They should just be used against misleading/low quality answers.

Comment: Don't get it personal. Just tried to clarify your probable misunderstanding of the downvote that you received. If you like I can cast a downvote to your answer if you undelete it. Then you will see who not downvoted you;)

Comment: There were two delete suggestions to my answer. If it is deemed a really bad solution by the community, I concur. I still had to use it against an app that did not support UI Automation. (A ground up redesigned Chinese app.)

Comment: Using a Windows API is never a bad solution, in fact it's good. I also tried to share a good and standard way of UI Automation.  While your answer could be improved by adding solution to find the button as part of questions's requirement, but it didn't deserve downvotes, it's not misleading. Downvotes are more likely because of a discussion about closing and reopening the question with some non-C# guys! It resulted in a downvote attack to the question and answers, including mine.